# Installing Python on cygwin

Tags: python, linux, unix, cygwin

How do I install Python on cygwin? I downloaded the Python-2.7.2.tar and uncompressed it. What do I do with it now? I tried running install-sh but it says no input file specified

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the Cygwin setup, you can select packages to install (even on an existing installation of cygwin). You can select Python, for example.

Comment: Ah yes that was easy... just ran setup again and 'checked' Python. Thanks!